# Taking One Row and adding it to end of the row above it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to take one row and add it to the end of the row above it with VBA.

The range this macro is going affect is just going to be highlighted range.  I am trying to find the last cell in row A and take all of row B and paste it at the end of row A.

Everything that pops up in my search is about adding rows below rows not adding rows to rows.

The rows will vary in length.

The goal is to take all of the cells from a single row and just add them to the end of the row above.

Before:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

After:

| A header | Another header | Bnother header | Cnother header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | B | 2 |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just for the sake of understanding better, if you had 50 rows, 2 columns, the output would be 1 row with 100 columns?

Comment: well each row could be different columns in length. think of it as 50 rows with unknown column count each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each row will be different lengths, this gets a little tricker than my initial answer. This should get you in the ballpark though:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastReadCol As Integer
Dim writeCol As Integer

'figure out the last row
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row()

'figure out first empty column in row 1
writeCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column() + 1

'starting at row 2 to the lastrow, iterate each row
For j = 2 To lastRow

    'figure out how many columns are in this row
    lastReadCol = Cells(j, 1).End(xlToRight).Column()
            
    'loop through each column in this row
    For i = 1 To lastReadCol
    
        'copy the data
        Cells(1, writeCol).Value = Cells(j, i).Value
        
        'iterate to the next write column
        writeCol = writeCol + 1
   Next i
Next j
```

Comment: what if it doesnt start at A1? and its just a highllighted section of cells?

Comment: The flow is the same, you'll just be iterating across your selection, so there won't be a need to determine `lastRow` and instead you could do `for each rngCell in Selection.Rows()` (as an example). This is sufficiently complex enough that you may want to snag a developer on one of those websites where you can drop your requirements and folks will give you a quote for the work.

Comment: @PotterFan You should have included that requirement in your initial question. Once you have got an answer you can't add more requirements or conditions to what you originally asked. IOW, think before you ask! It is also better to talk about columns with letters 'A', 'B' etc and talk about rows with numbers like '1', '2', etc. as that is how they are called in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Please, also test the next code. It should  be very fast even for large selections. It returns in the next sheet after the active one, where the selection is done:

```
Sub selectionToARow()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, sl As Range, irow As Range, maxCol As Long, arr, i As Long, noCols As Long
  
  Set sl = Selection: Set ws = sl.Parent: Set wsDest = ws.Next
  
  ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To sl.rows.count * sl.Columns.count)
  
  maxCol = 1
  For Each irow In sl.rows
    noCols = ws.cells(irow.Row, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column - sl.column + 1
    For i = 1 To noCols
        arr(1, maxCol) = irow.cells(i).value: maxCol = maxCol + 1
    Next i
  Next
  'Keep only the loaded array elements:
  ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 1, 1 To maxCol - 1)
  'drop the array value in the next sheet, at once:
  wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr
End Sub
```